# Constructing a hierarchy tree in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, trie

I am trying to build a hierarchy tree for Category and Sub-category and so on from the facets that I am getting from the `SOLR`. The input is of the form:

```
['445',
79,
'398',
73,
'710',
32,
'398|760',
28,
'398|760|779',
28,
'445|446',
10]
```

where data in single quotes represents the categories and number after that represents frequency.

Given the above array, the output I need should be in the format:

```
[
    {
        "id": 445,
        "count": 79,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 446,
                "count": 10
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 398,
        "count": 73,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 760,
                "count": 28,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 779,
                        "count": 28
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 710,
        "count": 32
    }
]
```

I am trying to build tree out of the same- for an efficient solution, but not able to do the same. Would someone know how to get it working- or any other time efficient solution for the same.

Thanks!

Comment: I am rather confused by the intended trie purpose here. Usually you'd create a trie in JavaScript for autocomplete purposes such as if a user typed in a category name, which apparently you're working on category ids... What sort of trie structure were you aiming for? Given `398|730|607` I could design for you a tree such as `{398:{freq:73,760:{freq:28,779:{freq:28}},730:{freq:18,607:{freq:18}}}}` is that what you want? Or did you want a tree based on the category names like: `{'j':{'a':{'v':{'a':{...}}}}}`?

Comment: I've edited the question to showcase the final output that I am working towards, I thought of using Trie as the dictionary and then using the trie to build the final data structure (and Radix trees aren't just used for Autocomplete). But then any other approach would work as long as complexity remains O(n).

Comment: Why don't you split the data to first get the vertices of the tree and then get the edges? Or is it always like this : you get first edges and then verticies?

Comment: Well the source of the raw input is beyond my control, so I cannot assume that, but I could certainly modify it to get in the format that you mentioned- but I fail to understand how that would help ease the complexity. I have solved the problem by recursively forming buckets within buckets- but as can be expected with horrible tradeoff in terms of both time and space!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want with the exception that nodes with no children will still have a node.children property so you can see how many children any node in the tree has by using `node.children.length`

```
var o=["445", 79, "398", 73, "710", 32, "398|760", 28, "398|760|779", 28, "445|446", 26, "710|1045", 25, "445|452", 24, "381", 19, "445|943", 19, "398|730", 18, "398|730|607", 18, "367", 16, "445|446|451", 15, "351", 14, "351|363", 14, "351|363|365", 14, "381|395", 14, "381|395|566", 14, "445|526", 14, "445|526|769", 14, "367|372", 12, "710|1045|1119", 11, "398|410", 10, "398|483", 9, "445|452|743", 8, "367|372|377", 7, "398|483|757", 7, "445|446|792", 7, "445|452|744", 7, "445|452|719", 6, "398|410|411", 5];

var nodeMap={};
var nodeLevels=[];
for(var i=0;i<o.length;i+=2)
{
    var catLineage=o[i].split('|');
    var cat=catLineage[catLineage.length-1];
    var depth=catLineage.length;
    while(depth>nodeLevels.length){nodeLevels.push([]);}
    nodeMap[cat]={id:cat,count:o[i+1],depth:depth,parents:catLineage.slice(0,catLineage.length-1)};
    nodeLevels[depth-1].push(cat);
}
var tree=[];
var treeNodeLookup={};
for(var i=0;i<nodeLevels.length;i++)
{
    for(var j=0;j<nodeLevels[i].length;j++)
    {
        var nodeId=nodeLevels[i][j];
        var nodeDepth=nodeMap[nodeId].depth;
        var nodeCount=nodeMap[nodeId].count;
        var parents=nodeMap[nodeId].parents;
        var pointer={children:tree};
        if(parents.length>0){pointer=treeNodeLookup[parents[0]];}
        var node={id:nodeId,count:nodeCount,children:[]};
        pointer.children.push(node);
        treeNodeLookup[nodeId]=pointer.children[pointer.children.length-1];
    }
}
console.log(tree);
```

Using `console.log(JSON.stringify(tree));` my output is:

```
[{"id":"445","count":79,"children":[{"id":"446","count":26,"children":[]},{"id":"452","count":24,"children":[]},{"id":"943","count":19,"children":[]},{"id":"526","count":14,"children":[]},{"id":"451","count":15,"children":[]},{"id":"769","count":14,"children":[]},{"id":"743","count":8,"children":[]},{"id":"792","count":7,"children":[]},{"id":"744","count":7,"children":[]},{"id":"719","count":6,"children":[]}]},{"id":"398","count":73,"children":[{"id":"760","count":28,"children":[]},{"id":"730","count":18,"children":[]},{"id":"410","count":10,"children":[]},{"id":"483","count":9,"children":[]},{"id":"779","count":28,"children":[]},{"id":"607","count":18,"children":[]},{"id":"757","count":7,"children":[]},{"id":"411","count":5,"children":[]}]},{"id":"710","count":32,"children":[{"id":"1045","count":25,"children":[]},{"id":"1119","count":11,"children":[]}]},{"id":"381","count":19,"children":[{"id":"395","count":14,"children":[]},{"id":"566","count":14,"children":[]}]},{"id":"367","count":16,"children":[{"id":"372","count":12,"children":[]},{"id":"377","count":7,"children":[]}]},{"id":"351","count":14,"children":[{"id":"363","count":14,"children":[]},{"id":"365","count":14,"children":[]}]}]
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne! Looks perfect- the empty children property ain't an issue at all! Really appreciate the help! I guess there's no way to boil it down to O(n)!

Comment: If you wanted to add big-O complexity support, you should be using a node tree, which is very different from a trie. I don't think a high level language like JavaScript, which is interpreted by one of the many browsers out there, or JavaScript engines for the case of node.js, would be able to make much sense of such performance calculations. But I can understand how a lower language out there such as Java would benefit greatly from them due to the strong typing.